# Remotely execute `shutdown /sg`

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, ssh

I'm using a raspberry pi to shut down my Windows 10 Computer. 
My RPI uses SSH with a private key to execute a `shutdown /s /t 30` command on my computer.

But, for optimization reasons, I want to use the `shutdown /sg` command; by doing so my applications will open automatically before I unlock my session.

However, `shutdown /sg` needs to be executed on a Desktop Session.

How I can execute a script on my desktop from command communicated over SSH?

Comment: You could try using Enter-PSsession to execute your code

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help.

I tried to use `Invoke-Command` but Powershell is not my cup of tea.

But, I find a solution :

I created a Task (named *ShutdownSG_over_SSH_from_RPI*) in Task Manager which execute `shutdown \sg` command.

From my RPI, I execute this command over SSH :

`powershell -command "Start-ScheduledTask -TaskPath '\MyTaskPath\' -TaskName 'ShutdownSG_over_SSH_from_RPI'"`

I know it isn't the best solution but it works.

Answer (score -1):

If you have `PowerShell 6.0`, support for SSH connection has been added to `New-PSSession`, `Enter-PSSession` and `Invoke-Command`

This requires software to be installed on both your Raspberry PI and your computer.

Microsoft have provided a nice article explaining how to achieve this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ssh-remoting-in-powershell-core?view=powershell-6

You should also look at the documentation for `Invoke-Command`, as that's the easiest way to execute commands and scripts remotely:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-6